# Insert two or three values in a column in the postgresql database

Tags: database, postgresql, insert

there is postgresql database named movie_db, and created a table named films as following:

```
CREATE TABLE movies (
title       varchar(128) NOT NULL,
description varchar(256) NOT NULL,
directors   varchar(128)[],
roles       varchar(128)[]
);
```

I want to insert the following data:

```
title   description          directors     roles
a       the love of wind      tom       tom, kaon, kate 
b       the second way story  john      jack, mark
```

for example, you know the movie has not just one actor, for example, movie has the actor(roles): tom, kaon, and kate. I want to insert these two data into the table using the following command:

```
insert into movies(title, description, directors, roles) values('a',    
'the love of wind', 'tom',{'tom, kano, kate'}))
```

but there is error:

```
 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "{"
 LINE 1: ...ors, roles) values('a', 'the love of wind', 'tom',{'tom,   
 kan..
                                                         ^
```

Could you help me to deal with it, thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the reason for this de-normalized model? You should start with a properly normalized model first, and only de-normalize if there is a good reason for it. Apart from that: the syntax to specify arrays is documented in the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-IO

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I solved it after I read the document! But I have another question based on this issue, I will post my question in another post , please give me your hand! thanks! I will give you the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks@a_horse_with_no_name, I solved it, after I read the document about array in the postgresql document.

The answer about my issue posed:

```
insert into movies(title, description, directors, roles) values('a',     
'the love of wind', '{"tom"}','{"tom", "kano", "kate"}');
```

Comment: I personally prefer the explicit syntax: `array['tom']` or `array['tom', 'kano', 'kate']` - less trouble with single/double quotes